# How to filter firebase data using a where clause with FieldPat.documentId

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to retrieve data with

```
Stream<List<User>> getUsers(User user) {
    List<String> userFilter = List.from(user.swipeLeft!)
      ..addAll(user.swipeRight!)
      ..add(user.uid!);

    return _firebaseFirestore
        .collection('users')
        .where('interestedIn', isEqualTo: 'HIRING')
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereNotIn: userFilter)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snap) {
      return snap.docs.map((doc) => User.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
    });
  }
```

I get an error
**An error occurred while parsing query arguments, this is most likely an error with this SDK.
Invalid query. When querying with FieldPath.documentId() you must provide a valid document ID, but it was an empty string.**

My data in firebase is structured as follows
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firebase you cannot filter with the document id, you can only filter with the fields in the document, a way a simple solution will be to generate a unique id by your self using packages like [uuid](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) and then save the document with the id and also save the id inside the document fields then you can filter with the id in the document field